# If $p$ is prime and $\gcd(m,p) = 1$ show that $\gcd(m,p^k) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

If $p$ is prime and $\gcd(m,p) = 1$ show that $\gcd(m,p^k) = 1$ where $k\geq1 $.

I think I have come up with a solution:

Suppose $m$ has prime factorization $m = p_1^{a_1}...p_n^{a_n}$ where $p_i$ is prime. Since $\gcd(m,p) = 1$ none of $p_i = p$. Now if $\gcd(m,p^k) \neq 1$ then the $\gcd$ must be $p^n$ with $0< n \leq k$. Note that the divisors of $m$ are the integers $p_1^{\bar{a_1}}...p_n^{\bar{a_n}}$ with $0\leq \bar{a_i} \leq a_i$.

So then we must have that $p^n = p_1^{\bar{a_1}}...p_n^{\bar{a_n}}$  so then both numbers must have the same prime factorization so that means that one of $p_i = p$ a contradiction. Which proves the result.

Is this argument fine?

Comment: Looks good. Longer than necessary. If $\gcd(m,p^k)\gt 1$, then some prime $q$ divides $m$ and $p^k$. Argue that $q=p$ from Euclid's Lemma, if a prime $q$ divides a product it divides one of the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine, though it feels a bit elaborate to start speaking of prime factorizations for this case (but it is still an excellent way to *think* about gcds in general).

It would probably be enough to say something like

> Since $\gcd(m,p)=1$, $p$ cannot divide $m$ (otherwise $p$ would be a greater common divisor).
>
> The only divisors of $p^k$ are $p^n$ for $0\le n\le k$ and if any of those *except* $1$ divides $m$, then $p$ will also divide $m$, which we know it doesn't. So $1$ is the *only* (positive) common divisor of $m$ and $p^k$.

Comment: Worth strong emphasis: it is not "enough" to say what is said above because it does not *justify* the claim that "the only divisors of $p^k$
 are ...". Usually this is justified by invoking FTA = existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations (or closely related results). It is essential to *explicitly* invoke such supporting Theorems *by name* in order to obtain a complete correct proof. There is nothing at all "elaborate" about doing such. $\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

More generally,  $\gcd(m,n)=1$ iff $\gcd(m^k,n^l)=1$ for $k,l\in\Bbb N$.

Proof: If $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then by Euclidean algorithm $\exists\, a,b\in\Bbb Z$ such that $$am+bn=1.\tag1$$ Taking $k+l$-th power of both sides of $(1)$, we have
$$\left(\sum_{j=0}^{l}{k+l\choose j}a^{k+l-j}b^jm^{l-j}n^{j}\right)m^k+\left(\sum_{j=l+1}^{k+l}{k+l\choose j}a^{k+l-j}b^jm^{k+l-j}n^{j-l}\right)n^l=1.$$
So, $\gcd(m^k,n^l)=1.$ Only if part of the proof is easier.